# trying print data from an xml file using $.get() in jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

cant really seem to figure out what i am doing wrong. Totally puzzled. 
I am simply trying to print the title field from this xml

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/communications%40doitt.nyc.gov/public/full?max-results=3
```

Here is my html and jquery

```
<div id="outputTitle"></div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $.get('https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/communications%40doitt.nyc.gov/public/full?max-results=3', function(data){
        $(data).find("title").each(function(){
            $("#outputTitle").append($(this)+ "<br />");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/teJS3/1/

Comment: The fiddle gets a "not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." error. Are you getting that on your own site, too?

Comment: @Barmar--Interesting. I didnt notice that until now.

Comment: Isn't your first instinct when a JS program doesn't work as expected to check the console for errors? It should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getJSON and add the needed parameter to your URL.

Then manipulate the data as you like ( I just print the whole feed as JSON in the example ). --> http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/teJS3/3/

more here --> [Sample Using Google Calendar API JSON Output](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/cal_sample)

```
// handler function
var handleData = function (data,txt,jqXHR) {
    var feed = data.feed; // your feed is here

    $("#outputTitle").text(JSON.stringify(feed));
};

//    use getJSON and add alt=json-in-script as parameters to your url
$.getJSON('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/communications%40doitt.nyc.gov/public/full?alt=json-in-script&callback=?', handleData );
```

Comment: @Antonis--this is great but what is that argument jqXHR that you are passing? What does that signify

Comment: @soum I'm used to writing all the arguments that the default jQuery API uses. See here -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/